# How to fetch data from table when multiple condition met

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below mentioned table.

```
ID    CFE     Val1    Val2
1     123     A       B
2     123     A       C
3     123     A       B
4     456     A       B
5     456     C       B
6     789     C       D
```

I want to fetch those records where my `CFE` value is grater than 1 and `Val1` value is "A" and `Val2` value is "B", or `Val1` value is anything (other than "A") but `Val2` value is "B".

And in one column it shows the count (`Count1`=Total count and `Count2`= count where criteria met) of `CFE`.

Required Output:

```
ID    CFE     Val1    Val2 Count1   Count2
1     123     A       B    3        2
3     123     A       B    3        2
4     456     A       B    2        2
5     456     C       B    2        2
```

Comment: I rolled back the edit, because the author already flagged the question as `mysql` and not `sql server`

Comment: How did you compress CFE 123 down to two rows? If it's grouping by CFE, Val1 and Val2, shouldn't you have id = 2 and Val2 = c?

Comment: @Xedni No, that not match the required condition.

Comment: Then what is the decision procedure which explains how you condensed the three CFE: 123 rows down to what you listed in the "Required Output?. Why did we choose to includes rows with IDs 1 and 3, but not 2?

Comment: @Xedni decision procedure is that first i should have `CFE` same value count >1 in whole database, second my Value of `Val1` and `Val2` should be "A" and "B" respectively and last where i have `Val1` other than "A" but `Val2` as "B".

Answer (score 1):

This would do that

```
;with src (ID, CFE, Val1, Val2) as
(
    select 1, 123, 'A', 'B' union all
    select 2, 123, 'A', 'C' union all
    select 3, 123, 'A', 'B' union all
    select 4, 456, 'A', 'B' union all
    select 5, 456, 'C', 'B' union all
    select 6, 789, 'C', 'D' 
), ct as
(
    select 
        s.ID,
        s.CFE,
        s.Val1,
        s.Val2,
        count1 = (select count(1)
                  from src i
                  where s.CFE = i.CFE)
    from src s
    where (s.CFE > 1 and s.Val1 = 'A' and s.Val2 = 'B')
        or (s.Val1 != 'A' and s.Val2 = 'B')
)
select 
    Id,
    CFE, 
    Val1,
    Val2,
    Count1,
    Count2 = (select count(1)
              from ct i
              where o.CFE = i.CFE)
from ct o
```

Comment: Oh crap, sorry, I didn't see this was `mysql`. I was writing that in `tsql` so the syntax may not apply. I'll leave it up in case you can reverse engineering the mysql syntax, but that's probably why it's erroring. My bae.

Comment: Not able to convert it in Mysql, can you please help here.

Comment: I modified it so it doesn't use the `over/partition by` clause.  I think that should be iso-standard SQL. Beyond that though, unfortunately I don't know much about mysql syntax. I could try to tell you my reasoning behind my decisions though if you're still stuck

Comment: Didn't work since i have the read only access of database...:(